# compare array values against array elements

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$check = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

which I want to check against another array so that the values of `$check` should match the keys in `$actual`

```
$actual = ['a' => 'one', 'b' => 'two', 'c' => 'three'];
```

I can't use `array_diff() === []` since array diff works on comparing the values and in this case I want to compare the values of one array against the keys in another.

Comment: use array_keys first. Then - array_diff

Comment: try `array_diff_key`...

Comment: Actually what you want to do??

Comment: @FrayneKonok and if read the question?

Comment: Check this: [https://3v4l.org/t9Nun](https://3v4l.org/t9Nun)

Comment: no diff with the answer in fact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array_keys();

```
<?php
$check = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$actual = ['a' => 'one', 'b' => 'two', 'c' => 'three'];

$result = array_diff(array_keys($actual), $check);
print_r($result);
```

In this case array_diff returns a empty array because all keys are found